# putting multibinding on a single line in xaml

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, binding, multibinding

Is there a way to take this multibinding:

```
<TextBox.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LogicConverter}">
        <Binding ElementName="prog0_used" Path="IsEnabled" />
        <Binding ElementName="prog0_used" Path="IsChecked" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBox.IsEnabled>
```

and put is all on one line, as in `<TextBox IsEnabled="" />`?

If so, where can I learn the rules of this formattiong?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, but I'm interested to know.

Comment: bind it directly to prog0_used with your custom converter prog0_used-to-boolean ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A better (and simpler) approach would be to define a style as a resource which you can easily apply to any TextBox:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:MyLogicConverter x:Key="LogicConverter" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" x:Key="MultiBound">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LogicConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="switch" Path="IsEnabled" />
                    <Binding ElementName="switch" Path="IsChecked" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox Name="switch" />
    <TextBox Name="textBox2" Text="Test" Style="{StaticResource MultiBound}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 8):

This can be done with a custom markup extension:

```cs
public class MultiBinding : System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding
{
    public MultiBinding (BindingBase b1, BindingBase b2)
    {
        Bindings.Add(b1);
        Bindings.Add(b2);
    }

    public MultiBinding (BindingBase b1, BindingBase b2, BindingBase b3)
    {
        Bindings.Add(b1);
        Bindings.Add(b2);
        Bindings.Add(b3);
    }

    // Add more constructors if you need.
}
```

Usage:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{local:MultiBinding
    {Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=prog0_used},
    {Binding IsChecked, ElementName=prog0_used},
    Converter={StaticResource LogicConverter}}">
```

Comment: Removed comment and created a new answer.

Comment: Can be done with one constructor using the params keyword: `public MultiBinding (params BindingBase[] bindings)`

Comment: This is a great solution! And gets around the xaml issues of the built in Multibinding.  Thanks for this

Comment: [@BalintPogatsa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1471878/balintpogatsa) That was my first thought as well, but the `params` keyword doesn't appear to work here - compilation fails with **`error MC3009: Cannot find a public constructor for 'MultiBinding' that takes 2 arguments.`**. Have you gotten it to work with this method; and if so, how?

Answer (score 4):

For MultiBinding there is no shorthand string. You need to use the expanded element syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I tried using Discord's answer, but it didn't work right out of the box. To make it work I added a new constructor:

```
public class MultiBinding : System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding
{
    public MultiBinding(BindingBase b1, BindingBase b2, object converter)
    {
        Bindings.Add(b1);
        Bindings.Add(b2);
        Converter = converter as IMultiValueConverter;
    }
}
```

Usage will then be like this:

```
    <TextBox IsEnabled="{local:MultiBinding {Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=prog0_used}, 
{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=prog0_used}, 
{StaticResource LogicConverter}}">
```

Comment: I'd like to accomplish this since I have so many controls that need to react to multiple booleans, but mine's not behaving: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057720/inline-multibinding-not-working-as-expected